# Does a photon form a black-hole when it is squeezed into a box of Planck length?

Tags: black-holes, wavelength

Is it true that if there is a photon with a wavelength that could fit in a box that is equal to or smaller than the Planck length, then it forms a black-hole? Originally I thought, since a Planck length isn't about the length but the point at which physics will produce weird numbers, that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why don't you do the math?

Comment: There are no photons in General Relativity and no black holes in the Quantum Field Theory.